# Saving data to sqlite database and updating recycler list adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm a newbie to android app dev and I have one little problem. I'm developing a note app with a single activity(MainActivity) which has a NavHost and host three fragments(NewNoteFragment, NoteListFragment and NoteUpdateFragment). The note details are stored in a sqlite database.

Whenever user creates new note or update the existing note, the changes can only be stored to the database in NewNoteFragment or NoteUpdateFragment's onPause override i.e when the user navigates from the said fragments to the NoteListFragment. Although the changes were saved but the recyclerView in the NoteListFragment doesn't update immediately until i kinda navigate away from the NoteListFragment to other fragment.
When I check the logcat i noticed the onResume override(which is where I called my adapter.notifydatasetchanged() method) in my NoteListFragment is called before onPause override of the replaced fragments.

Is there a way to change the fragments navigating behaviour where onpause is called before the onresume? Or any better way to achieve my said aim.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set onPause to be called before. Since you are using fragments try to update the recyclerView onViewCreated() function of Fragment.

Comment: Also you should try to use Room and livedata to save the notes https://medium.com/mindorks/using-room-database-with-livedata-android-jetpack-cbf89b677b47

Comment: I'll work on room, thanks. But, do you updating the adapter in onViewCreated would work? It's only called once, as is in my case.

Comment: It should, or you could put that login onAttach(). Since there is no code to check, I can't be 100 percent sure checking it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the Android Lifecycle, it is always set.

[image: Android Lifecycle]

I would advise using Room and LiveData, any changes in the database would automatically update the RecyclerView you mentioned.

You can read more about live data [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata)

Comment: Room is the next aspect on my agenda. I just wanna have experience with Sqlite before moving onto room. Thank you for your time, I'll look into it.